# Show property of compact operators over Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, compact-operators

A colleague of mine showed me the following problem:

Let H be a Hilbert space, show that every compact operator $T:H\rightarrow H$ is the limit of a succesion of compact operators of finite rank(That is, their range is a finite dimension vectorial space)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You mean finite rank: their range is a finite dimensional space.

Comment: @Robert Israel, I edited that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space) of $T$.

Comment: I'll try that, I don't know anything about polar decomposition